# Chosen Dropdown cascading issue

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-chosen, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) cdn to display dropdown with cascading. But I see one more extra dropdown displayed after selecting value in first dropdown. total 3 dropdowns are populated one is select group and other 2 are Select App. Out of 2 newly populated dropdowns one has app values with no chosen style and other is empty select app dropdown with chosen style. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Html Razor code

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedGroup, Model.Groups, "Select Group")
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedApp, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select")

Jquery Code

 $('#SelectedGroup').chosen();
 $('#SelectedApp').chosen();


$('#SelectedGroup').on('change', function (event, ui) {
        var project_id = this.value;
        var appdropdown = $('#SelectedApp');
        appdropdown.prop("disabled", true);
        appdropdown.empty();
        appdropdown.append($('<option></option>').val("-1").html('Select'));
        nextLinkApps = $('#ServiceUri').val();

        loadApps(); // This is append values to option

    });
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which part is not working?

Comment: on dropdown change, it adds duplicate dropdown next to that dropdown.

Comment: @Chandana check my updated answer for hide duplicate dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jquery**

```
 $('#SelectedGroup').chosen();

 $('#SelectedGroup').on('change', function (event, ui) {
    var project_id = this.value;
    $('#AppValues').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#AppValues').empty();
    loadApps(project_id); // This is append values to option

});

function loadApps(value)
{
   switch(value)
   {
     case 1:
        $('#AppValues').append($('<option>', { 
                      value: value1,
                      text : value1 
                       }));
     break;
     case 2:
        $('#AppValues').append($('<option>', { 
                      value: value2,
                      text : value2 
                       }));
     break;  
   }
  $('#SelectedApp').prop("disabled", false);
   //here u can populate SelectedApp values
  $('#SelectedApp').chosen();
}
```

if u want a complete idea about cascading dropdowns [check this plugin](http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html)

`for hiding duplicate dropdown without chosen class you can try this code`

**html**

```
 <div id="dropdownList">
    <select id="SelectedGroup" class="chosen">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="AppValues" disabled> // AppValuesis not chosen
    </select>
    <select id="SelectedApp" class="chosen" disabled> // SelectedApp is chosen
    </select>
    </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#dropdownList select').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('chosen'))  // or whatever the css class for chosen dropdown
        $(this).hide();
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed this line:

```
        appdropdown.prop("disabled", false);
```

and filled the loadApps function. You can substitute your own AJAX call or data.

```
function loadApps(project_id)
{
  switch(project_id)
  {
      case "1":
          appdropdown.append($("<option>").val("1").text("App1")); 
          break;

      case "2":
          appdropdown.append($("<option>").val("2").text("App2"));
          break;   
  }
  appdropdown.trigger("chosen:updated")
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UPkkX/3/). Feel free to edit if you want to try to replicate your problem further.

Comment: Kravits, Once I select value in dropdown it adds extra dropdown right to it. I think chosen is adding extra dropdown. I have $('#SelectedApp').chosen(); on document.ready. I think this is adding duplicate dropdown. How to hide other dropdown with out chosen style?

Comment: OK, I can not replicate your issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/UPkkX/3/ I think the issue must be in your JavaScript somewhere else. Post more code if you need. Otherwise just figure out where it is in the DOM and you can hide it: $("select").hide();